# How to download linux kernel source code

Tags: apt, 20.04

I need to take a look at the ext4 fs files.
I tried apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r). But it says:

```
Picking 'linux-signed' as source package instead of 'linux-image-5.4.0-72-generic'
```

Please suggest on how to download source code on ubuntu 20.04 and the relevant path of the source code.

Comment: took 15 seconds research

Comment: Please check the edits